# Como construir cabeçalho com logo ao centro e informações na esquerda e na direita

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou tentando criar um cabeçalho com informações a direita, um logo no centro e informações a esquerda, mas o que fiz não fica nem perto do que preciso, fiz uns testes com algumas linhas que encontrei no SO mas ficou muito mal formatado por mim.

Minha versão do `Bootstrap` é essa: `Bootstrap v3.3.4`

O que preciso é isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que semanticamente não é legal usar tabelas, mas até isso tentei, o que fiz até agora é isso:

```css
.flex-parent {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}

.col {
    -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
```

```html
<!-- TOP INFO -->
<div class="top_info">
 <!-- CONTAINER -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3">         
    <div class="flex-parent col">
     <div class="flex-parent">
      <div class="flex-parent">
       <div class="flex-child" align="center"><img src="https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/_imagens/user.fw.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-parent col">
       <div class="flex-child"><a href="minha-conta-login.php">Faça login</a></div>
       <div class="flex-child"><a href="cadastro-cliente.php">ou Cadastre-se</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6" align="center"><a href="index.php"><img src="_imagens/logo-rendamais.jpg" width="314" height="100" alt=""/></a></div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">         
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1" align="hight">ÍCONE</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" align="left">FACEBOOK</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1" align="left">ICONE</div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" align="left">INSTAGRAN</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- TOP INFO -->
```

O resultado disso pode ser visto online aqui:
[Página em desenvolvimento](https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/index.php)

Comment: Eu utilizaria grid em conjunto com flexbox, tem alguma limitação quanto a compatibilidade de navegadores? - [grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) / [flex](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: Olá @Renan, não tenho nenhuma.

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap vc está usando?

Comment: Olá @hugocsl, a minha versão é Bootstrap v3.3.4.

Answer (score 2):

A estrutura que vc montou pro HTML da sua barra superior tem algum errinhos de organização. Por exemplo vc não deve usar um `container` dentro do outro, e a forma como vc dividiu as `rows` e `cols` tb não ficou legal.

Eu tente usar o máximo do seu código e algumas classes de `flexbox`, apenas para ajustar o conteúdo dentro das `col-`

Veja como ficou o resultado.

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.d-flex.end {
  /* alinga o conteúdo a direita da div */
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <div class="container">
    <!-- TOP INFO -->
    <div class="top_info">
      <!-- CONTAINER -->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="d-flex" >
              <img src="https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/_imagens/user.fw.png" width="32" height="32" alt=""/>
              <div>
                <a href="minha-conta-login.php">Faça login</a><br>
                <a href="cadastro-cliente.php">ou Cadastre-se</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  
          <div class="col-xs-6 text-center">
              <a href="index.php">
                <img src="https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/_imagens/logo-rendamais.jpg" width="314" height="100" alt=""/>
              </a>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="d-flex end" >
                <div class="left text-right">
                  <img src="https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/_imagens/user.fw.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/><br>
                  <img src="https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/_imagens/user.fw.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/><br>
                  <img src="https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/_imagens/user.fw.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/><br>
                  <img src="https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/_imagens/user.fw.png" width="16" height="16" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="right text-left">
                  <div class="">ÍCONE</div>
                  <div class="">FACEBOOK</div>
                  <div class="">ICONE</div>
            <div class="">INSTAGRAN</div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**OBS:** Aqui no *Snippet* eu coloquei para ficar tudo em uma linha só, mesmo em telas pequenas. Porém, é preciso que vc trate essa parte de forma que a responsividade fique legal pra vc ok. Vc pode usar `media querys` pra isso ou usar classes do próprio grid do Bootstrap... 
Vc pode consultar isso aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-mixed

Comment: Olá @hugocsl, tem como deixar para por uma imagem separada do texto nessa ultima coluna, por exemplo, ícone do facebook e instagran em cada um em sua coluna e o texto em outra?

Comment: @adventistapr tem sim, só que separando imagem e texto um em cada coluna não faria muito sentido... Vc pode trabalhar esse ícone de várias maneiras, como por exemplo no `::after` ou algo assim... Mas vou ver se edito a resposta da forma que vc quer.

Comment: Na verdade preciso de algo que deixe o icone a esquerda e o texto a direita, mas não imagino como fazer.

Comment: @adventistapr pronto fiz umas mudanças no CSS e separei os ícons em uma div, e depois outra div com os textos...

Comment: @adventistapr vc acha que a resposta foi útil para vc? Vi que até já até usou parte dela no seu código etc. Se ficou alguma dúvida ou eu puder te ajudar mais em algo é só me dar um toque. Em breve os pontos de Gratificação vão expirar serão perdidos. Não voltarão para vc, nem irão para ninguém da comunidade. Além disso a sua pergunta continuará pendente como Pergunta sem Resposta Aceita...

Comment: Rapaz tinha esquecido da gratificação, valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: @adventistapr sem problemas, obrigado pela consideração :)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma estrutura parecida com:

```
flex-container
├── flex-esquerda
├── flex-centro
└── flex-direita
```

Onde a parte esquerda e direita vão ter a propriedade [`flex-grow: 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) para que não aumentem de tamanho automaticamente para preencher o elemento pai, e o elemento do centro terá [`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) para que apenas o tamanho dele aumente.

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: middle;
  border: 1px solid #7FDBFF;
}

/* Centraliza conteúdo vertical e horizontalmente */
.flex-esquerda,
.flex-direita,
.flex-centro {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-esquerda,
.flex-direita {
  background: #7FDBFF;
  flex-basis: 100px; /* define um tamanho */
  flex-grow: 0; /* não permite que aumente automaticamente */
}

.flex-centro {
  flex-grow: 1; /* permite que aumente automaticamente */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-esquerda">
    Esquerda
  </div>
  <div class="flex-centro">
    Centro
  </div>
  <div class="flex-direita">
    Direita
  </div>
</div>
```